# Create a MS-Word Addin Setup

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, inno-setup, office-2007

How can I create an Inno Setup for a MS-Word AddIn?

There is some code snippet for doing the AddIn registration?

Comment: What version of MS Office are you targeting with your add-in ?

Comment: I'm installing in an Office 2010, but It should be Office 2007 compatible.

Comment: How would you register them manually? Once you know that, It's normally trivial to replicate that using Inno.

Comment: I'm asking how register manually, but there is another problem. After the register the DDL should be declared `Full Trust` and there is no `how-to` for doing that, only a sample on Microsoft site that is not avaliable for download!

Comment: @Victor Well actually your question was "How can I create an Inno Setup for a MS-Word AddIn?". I assumed you know how to do it manually from your testing.

Comment: No, I don't know. This is my question. How-to install MS-Word AddIn manually.

Answer (score 1):

VTSO Setup is different from normal setup. you can see steps at mdsn.

you may get some error while loading the Click Once file. for that refer to same issue and solution.

write in command prompt:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
Mage.exe -cc
```

Comment: I want to build a installer, but I don't want to use the ClickOnce or another Visual Studio installer. Theses installers has some limitations.

Comment: @Victor, this is the only way you can make MS-Word AddIn setup, if you have created in .net

Comment: poor answer! If I know the steps to install a AddIn I can reproduce theses steps in another installer and make some improves the microsoft default installer doesn't allow.